# Why is this only working correctly on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a procedure

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function rescaleStuff ( )
    {
        jQuery('.children-have-equal-height').each(function(){
            var children = jQuery(this).children();
            var numChildren = children.length;
            if (numChildren > 1) 
            {
                var firstChild = children.first();
                var maxHeight = firstChild.height();
                firstChild.siblings().each(function()
                { 
                    var thisHeight = jQuery(this).height(); 
                    if (thisHeight > maxHeight) 
                        maxHeight = thisHeight;
                });
                children.height(maxHeight);
            }
        });
    }


    jQuery(window).load(function() {
         rescaleStuff();
    });

    jQuery(window).resize(function()
    { 
         rescaleStuff();
    });
</script>
```

which is intended to make all children of elements with class `children-have-equal-height` have a height equal to that of the tallest child. Why is it only working on page load, and then the `height` of the child elements stays the same as it was on page load?

Comment: Because the 2nd time they all have the same height that was calculated the 1st time?

Comment: As a sanity check, what does `console.log(numChildren)` give you on load, and on resize?

Comment: @manji Ah ... I should be setting their `min-height`, I think

Comment: Does the size of the first child ever change?

Comment: Try adding `children.removeAttr('style');` to clear the height before re-assigning the new height.

Comment: After you set the height once, the resize likely isn't resulting in the div's height changing, because you've set it.

Comment: If you set min-height the problem will be the same if they need to  shrink. They will not be able to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the height to 'auto' at the begining of rescaleStuff with this code:

`jQuery('.children-have-equal-height').children().height('auto')`

Comment: You're welcome. Could you please mark this question as solved? :-).